# Delete an image being used by another process

Tags: c#, svg

I am writing a winform application in C# to open an image and overlay another image on top of it.

The bottom image is a .jpg and the top one is a .bmp converted from .svg. The .jpg and the .svg are the only ones I want to keep in the folder. The .bmp works as a temp.

I was using the following code to overlay the images. But I am having trouble to delete the temp .bmp as it is used by another process. I think it is this combine code still have access to the last .bmp file.

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

```
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FailInfo.Text = "";

        deletebmp(strFolderPath); 

        ...

        // Check if the specified front image exists. Yes, show the file name and convert SVG to BMP. No, show the error msg.
        if (File.Exists(strFilePathF))
        {
            labelFront.Text = strFileNameF;
            var svgConvert = SvgDocument.Open(svgFilePathF);
            svgConvert.Draw().Save(bmpFilePathF);
            pictureBoxFront.Image = Image.FromFile(strFilePathF);
        }
        else
        {
            labelFront.Text = "Couldn't find the file!";
            pictureBoxFront.Image = null;
        }

        // Check if the specified back image exists. Yes, show the file name and convert SVG to BMP. No, show the error msg.   
        if (File.Exists(strFilePathBF))
        {
            labelBack.Text = strFileNameBF;
            strFilePathB = strFilePathBF;
            pictureBoxBack.Image = Image.FromFile(strFilePathB);
            labelResult.Text = "FAIL";
            labelResult.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
            var svgConvert = SvgDocument.Open(svgFilePathBF);
            bmpFilePathB = strFolderPath + strFileNameBF + ".bmp";
            svgConvert.Draw().Save(bmpFilePathB);
            svgFilePathB = svgFilePathBF;
            inspectionres(svgFilePathB);
            labelreason.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (File.Exists(strFilePathBP))
        {
            labelBack.Text = strFileNameBP;
            strFilePathB = strFilePathBP;
            pictureBoxBack.Image = Image.FromFile(strFilePathB);
            labelResult.Text = "PASS";
            labelResult.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
            var svgConvert = SvgDocument.Open(svgFilePathBP);
            bmpFilePathB = strFolderPath + strFileNameBP + ".bmp";
            svgConvert.Draw().Save(bmpFilePathB);
            svgFilePathB = svgFilePathBP;
            inspectionres(svgFilePathB);
            labelreason.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            labelBack.Text = "Couldn't find the file!";
            pictureBoxBack.Image = null;
            labelResult.Text = "ERROR";
            labelResult.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255);
            labelreason.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    //
    // Overlay the SVG file on top of the JPEG file
    //
    private Bitmap Combine(string jpegFile, string bmpFile)
    {        
        Image image1 = Image.FromFile(jpegFile);
        Image image2 = Image.FromFile(bmpFile);
        Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp))
        {
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(image1, 0, 0);
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(image2, 0, 0);
        }

        return temp;
    }

    //
    // Show the overlaid graphic in the picturebox
    //
    private void checkBoxOverlay_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FindFront)
                if (checkBoxOverlay.Checked)
                    pictureBoxFront.Image = Combine(strFilePathF, bmpFilePathF);
                else
                    pictureBoxFront.Image = Image.FromFile(strFilePathF);
            else
                pictureBoxFront.Image = null;

            if (FindBack)
                if (checkBoxOverlay.Checked)
                    pictureBoxBack.Image = Combine(strFilePathB, bmpFilePathB);
                else
                    pictureBoxBack.Image = Image.FromFile(strFilePathB);
            else
                pictureBoxBack.Image = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading image" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //
    // Option of changing the image folder
    //
    private void buttonPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog FolderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            strFolderPath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "\\";
        }
    }

    //
    // Pull the inspection result info from the SVG file
    //
    private void inspectionres(string filename)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
        XElement svg_Element = document.Root;
        string sb = null;

        var faillist = (from svg_path in svg_Element.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}text") select svg_path).ToList();

        foreach (var item in faillist)
        {
            sb += item.ToString();
        }
    }

    //
    // Delete all the .bmp files generated from .svg files
    //
    private void deletebmp(string path)
    {
        // Unload the images from the picturebox if applicable
        pictureBoxFront.Image = null;
        pictureBoxBack.Image = null;

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.bmp");
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i ++ )
            File.Delete(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your graphics object instead of creating it, you probably don't call g.Dispose(): `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp)) { /* code to edit here */ } /* return here */`

Comment: Is image2 the one you are trying to delete? I don't see anywhere that you are trying to delete the file?

Comment: @EBrown, I tried both way, it didn't work.

Comment: @RonBeyer, Yes, the image2 is the coverted .bmp file that I wanted to delete. The delete function is just a simple File.Delete(path) that resides in another function that I didn't post.

Comment: And where is this file being written? Are you sure that the file handles are closed correctly or is it really another process outside your control that is writing the file?

Comment: @RonBeyer, I added more codes to the post. This file is first converted from a .svg in the same folder and then overlaid to the .jpg. The final image is shown in a picturebox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Image` implements `IDisposable`, so simply setting the `pictureBox.Image` property to null will not release resources (in your case, the file). Your `Combine` method also leaves the images open. You have to call `Dispose` before attempting to delete the file:

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile(path1);
File.Delete(path1);  // error - file is locked 

Image image2 = Image.FromFile(path2);
image2.Dispose();
File.Delete(path2);  // works
```

An alternative approach (and I assume you're using WinForms here, in WPF it's a little different) would be to load the bitmap from the file manually (using `FromStream`). Then, you can close the stream immediately and delete the file:

```
Image image;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
}
pictureBox.Image = image;
File.Delete("e:\\temp\\copy1.png");  //works
```

Answer (score 1):

Vesan's answer didn't helped me so I found an different solution.
So I can safe/open an image and if I want instantly delete the image.

i used it for my dataGridView_SelectionChanged:

```
private void dataGridViewAnzeige_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imageAsByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(imageAsByteArray);
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are perfectly fine, but I've got a different approach.
Using Image abstract class, you will not get quite a lot of options for manipulating and resizing image.

Rather you do as follows:-

```cs
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap(item);
 img.SetResolution(100, 100);
 Image imgNew = Image.FromHbitmap(img.GetHbitmap());
 pictureBox1.Image = imgNew;
 img.Dispose();
```